# connecting android app and computer through adb for changing parameters

Tags: android, adb, connectivity

I am student in an bio medical Engineering and as a project, I am asked to make an app through which I can communicate the medical device(which is mainly a computer just a software is installed, which i want to access using android app). I have finished making the app. The only thing left is find a bridge which helps to change the parameters in the device when I make changes in my app.

I have tried using adb, but adb can only install and uninstall the .apk files.

Can anyone please suggest me some other way to proceed please.

I will be looking forward for the quick positive responses.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is going to need more information. In what ways is the app "finished"? What methods of communication does the "medical device" support? You may need to read the documentation for the specific device.

Comment: Thank you for your message. The medical device supports usb, wifi, bluetooth(I can use an external bluetooth dongle to connect if it faster). I want to change the function lets say. I want to increase and decrease the density. I just want that, when I change it on my androd phone, that chages on medical device's software as well